When does reinterpret_cast violate the law?
I've written a code that accumulates unnecessary memory space and gives it back when needed, organizing it as a stack (customers' requirements are strange).
void* stack = nullptr;

template <typename P>
void push(P* p) {
  // reinterpret memory space of *p as a storage for the address of the top element of the stack;
  *reinterpret_cast<void**>(p) = stack;
  // now *p is the top element, so update stack to point to *p;
  stack = p;
}

template <typename P>
P* pop() {
  if (stack == nullptr) throw;

  // get the address of the top element
  P* p = static_cast<P*>(stack);
  // now stack should point to the next element after *p, which address is stored in *p's memory space
  stack = *reinterpret_cast<void**>(stack);
  return p;
}

stack is a pointer to the top element. When a new memory space is pushed its first 8 bytes are used for storing the address of the previous element, stack is updated. A simple stack chain.
Problem
While I was trying to achieve this behavior the compiler often said this (I know that some memory manipulations are illegal):

assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported

I want to know whether my implementation is legal now or not?
Example
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

constexpr size_t bytes_8  = 8 * 8;
constexpr size_t bytes_20 = 8 * 20;
constexpr size_t bytes_50 = 8 * 50;

// we assume that std::bitset holds its data contigiously in the beginning

struct A {
  std::bitset<bytes_8> bits;
};

struct B {
  std::bitset<bytes_20> bits;
};

struct C {
  std::bitset<bytes_50> bits;
};

int main() {
  // Imagine they were allocated on heap:
  A a;  B b;  C c;

  std::cout << "Addresses" << '\n'
            << "a: " << &a << "\t"
            << "b: " << &b << "\t"
            << "c: " << &c
            << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;

  push<A>(&a);
  std::cout << "---------- push<A>(&a) ----------\n"
            << "'a' is the top element (and the only one), so 'stack' points to it,\n"
            << "meanwhile 'a' stores the address of the previous element (none)\n\n"
            << "stack: " << stack << "\ta.bits: " << std::hex << a.bits.to_ullong()
            << std::endl << std::endl;

  push<B>(&b);
  std::cout << "---------- push<B>(&b) ----------\n"
            << "now 'b' is the top element, so 'stack' updates to point to it,\n"
            << "'b' stores the address of the previous element (a)\n\n"
            << "stack: " << stack << "\tb.bits: " << std::hex << b.bits.to_ullong()
            << std::endl << std::endl;

  push<C>(&c);
  std::cout << "---------- push<C>(&c) ----------\n"
            << "finally 'c' is the top element and 'stack' points to it,\n"
            << "'c' stores the address of the previous element (b)\n\n"
            << "stack: " << stack << "\tc.bits: " << std::hex << c.bits.to_ullong()
            << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;


  auto p1 = pop<C>();
  std::cout << "---------- pop<C>() ----------\n"
            << "'b' is the top element and the next one after it is 'a'\n\n"
            << "ret: " << p1 << "\nstack: " << stack << "\tb.bits: " << std::hex << b.bits.to_ullong()
            << std::endl << std::endl;

  auto p2 = pop<B>();
  std::cout << "---------- pop<B>() ----------\n"
            << "'a' is the top element and the last one in the stack\n\n"
            << "ret: " << p2 << "\nstack: " << stack << "\ta.bits: " << std::hex << a.bits.to_ullong()
            << std::endl << std::endl;

  auto p3 = pop<A>();
  std::cout << "---------- pop<A>() ----------\n"
            << "the stack is empty\n\n"
            << "ret: " << p3 << "\nstack: " << "0x" << stack
            << std::endl << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

The output:
Addresses
a: 0x7fffffffdc20       b: 0x7fffffffdc40       c: 0x7fffffffdc60


---------- push<A>(&a) ----------
'a' is the top element (and the only one), so 'stack' points to it,
meanwhile 'a' stores the address of the previous element (none)

stack: 0x7fffffffdc20   a.bits: 0

---------- push<B>(&b) ----------
now 'b' is the top element, so 'stack' updates to point to it,
'b' stores the address of the previous element (a)

stack: 0x7fffffffdc40   b.bits: 7fffffffdc20

---------- push<C>(&c) ----------
finally 'c' is the top element and 'stack' points to it,
'c' stores the address of the previous element (b)

stack: 0x7fffffffdc60   c.bits: 7fffffffdc40


---------- pop<C>() ----------
'b' is the top element and the next one after it is 'a'

ret: 0x7fffffffdc60
stack: 0x7fffffffdc40   b.bits: 7fffffffdc20

---------- pop<B>() ----------
'a' is the top element and the last one in the stack

ret: 0x7fffffffdc40
stack: 0x7fffffffdc20   a.bits: 0

---------- pop<A>() ----------
the stack is empty

ret: 0x7fffffffdc20
stack: 0x0


I know that it is UB

Did you read this?

I'm not sure what you mean by "legal". You're not going to go to prison for this. C++ has a specifcation which tells you how to interpret your program as C++ (and in your case the conclusion is "this is not valid C++, and no futher consequences can be derived from the specification ", i.e. you're on your own). But you seem to know that already. Are you perhaps asking how one could write your code portably with well-defined behaviour?

It is strange that even though nothing tragic happens here: I just use memory as I want, this is not a valid C++... Why?

@frippe mostly yes

I want to use this method for freelist allocator and it will be a pity if it is just something broken (unportable, etc.)

You might want to "just use memory as I want," but if the C++ standard says it is UB in this case (and I admit I havent read all the details in your question, but you menioned you are aware is it UB), then you shouldn't. It's as simple as that. If you do there's no guarantee wahtsoever about the result of your program.

You just are temporarily trashing underlying memory of your objects by writing pointers there. Why? Out of memory? Use boost::intrusive::slist (or read its code for inspiration) to have container that does not own its elements.

There is no reason for this code to use void* (let alone void**) and fight/thwart/subvert the type system in order to accumulate unnecessary memory space and gives it back when needed.  Rethink the design.

@Eljay Does this type system adds any performance issues if it is so harshly muddled up by void*?

No, the type system often removes performance issues. qsort from the C standard library is often slower than std::sort, precisely because C++ holds onto the type information that lets the compiler make more aggressive optimisations

template and casting pointers to void* and back for something what looks like a stack, seems like someone do not understand how to use templates. Sadly example code is so heavily trimmed that it is impossible what is more bad there or how to improve it.

@ÖöTiib: I'm pretty sure OP is caching memory to sidestep new and delete

Does this type system adds any performance issues if it is so harshly muddled up by void*?  Leveraging the type system (which is used at compile-time) will improve performance, or at worst make no difference.  The current implementation's reliance on undefined behavior renders performance moot.

You can re-use the storage of objects once their lifetime ends, but you really should track the sizes.
struct frame {
    frame * ptr;
    std::size_t size;
};

frame* stack = nullptr;

template <typename P>
requires sizeof(P) >= sizeof frame
void push(P* obj) {
    p->~P();
    stack = new(p) frame{ stack, sizeof(P) };
}

template <typename P, typename... Args>
P* pop(Args&&... args) {
    if (stack == nullptr || stack->size != sizeof(P)) throw std::bad_alloc{};
    frame * top = stack;
    stack = stack->ptr;
    top->~frame();
    return new(top) P(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

But even if you do this, I would profile whether this scheme has any improvement over normal allocations. Most likely, you are adding a whole pile of restrictions to how you can allocate, for a negligible or possibly negative performance benefit.

As far as I can see, all of this strange code from me was caused because I completely forgot about new :)

The main difference is that the placement-new in this answer just uses the object at *p for its storage, whereas your reinterpret-cast pretends that an object of type P is a object of type void*, which is UB.

Your implementation can't possibly work as it stands. Your example with local objects is always undefined behaviour, as would any use with objects that haven't been destroyed.
Pushing an element onto your stack overwrites part of it. This is a lossy operation. The sizeof void* bytes at the start of *p's object representation are gone, never to be recovered. Even if you aren't using that object anymore, it's destructor still needs to run, and in general needs that data.

I agree but push should only be applied to memory parts that do not hold any information (trash)

@AlexanderS • the memory shown is not trash, it's in-use.  Until the object is destructed, after which it is available memory for re-use ... but you're re-using it when it is still a live object.  (And your code example is using automatic storage (the stack) live objects, but we're ignoring that because of the comment to ignore that and pretend they are on the dynamic free store (the heap).)
